# Alphanumeric Phone Number converter

Tags: java

This is just one that is a little over my head and my instructor doesn't speak english that well so I am just going to see if you guys can help me out. I am surprised I have gotten this far, but I have dug my way through the internet to help me out and now I am stuck. Here is my code.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phone {
    public static int getNumber(char uppercaseLetter) {

        char[] letter =
            {'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
             'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z'};

        int[] value = {2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6,
                       7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9};

        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++) {
            if (uppercaseLetter == letter[i]) {
                return value[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the phone number string :");

        String getNumber = input.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumber.length(); i++) {
            System.out.print(getNumber(getNumber.toUpperCase().charAt(i)));
        }
    }
}
```

So I was instructed to use the method `public static int getNumber(char upperCaseLetter)` to start it off. I must use a for loop, and within the for-loop body, convert only the letters to their equivalent number using the following algorithm: If the current character of `phoneNumberStr` is an uppercase letter, call the method `getNumber` to determine the number and append (or concatenate) to `phoneNumber`. The variable `phoneNumber` is also `String` variable. Note that to check if the character is a letter consider the ASCII range of uppercase
letters.

For example, `if(phoneNumberStr.charAt(i) == 65)` is true when the character at index i is A.

Also, recall that `if(phoneNumberStr.charAt(i) == ‘A’)` is the same expression as above.

If the current character of `phoneNumberStr` is NOT a letter, you will need to create a one-character
substring and then append/concatenate this substring to `phoneNumber` 
and then output the `phoneNumber`

this is a sample output but I can't figure out why my code is not outputting at all...

```
Case 1 (with hyphen)
Enter the phone number string
1-800-flowers<---User input
Phone #: 1-800-3569377
```

Comment: @Jongware It got me too. But user input is stored in `getNumber` and the function is called `getNumber` as well. Really confusing

Comment: Your program does produce an output: 0000003568377. So what's your question exactly?

Comment: Ah - the default return value for the *function* `getNumber` returns the wrong thing. Really minor, and easy to detect.

Comment: On quick look, looks like your problem is just that "return 0"... if that were instead "return uppercaseletter" I think you're OK. Problem is you're returning 0 instead of any non-ASCII characters.

Comment: `If the current character of phoneNumberStr is NOT a letter...` I dont see that part in your code

Comment: what to do in case of the letter is any character like * ? also "If the current character of phoneNumberStr is NOT a letter, you will need to create a one-character substring" what is the one-character ?

Answer (score 1):

Your code was mostly correct. The big problem was that you never checked whether or not the character was a letter. So, you would print out '0' for the part that should have just been printed verbatim (i.e. "1-800-").

You also had an extra 6 in the array (6 is only MNO, not MNOP). Read my comments and make sure you understand the fixes.

As for your statement:

> but I can't figure out why my code is not outputting at all...

Your old code was indeed outputting a result, just an incorrect one, which makes me think you're not running it correctly. Try getting a hello world example to work first. If you're still having issues getting outputs to work at all, you may need to add details about your development environment so we can figure out why you cannot get code to run at all.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Phone
{
    public static int getNumber(char uppercaseLetter)
    {

        char[] letter =
        { 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S',
                'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z' };

        // You had an extra 6 here
        int[] value = { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6,
                7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9 };

        for (int i = 0; i < letter.length; i++)
        {
            if (uppercaseLetter == letter[i])
            {
                return value[i];
            }
        }
        return 0;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the phone number string :");

        String getNumber = input.nextLine();
        for (int i = 0; i < getNumber.length(); i++)
        {
            // First you need to check if the character is a letter
            char c = getNumber.toUpperCase().charAt(i); // get the character
            int value = getNumber(c); // get the number associated w/ it

            if (value != 0)
            {
                System.out.print(value); // If getNumber(..) returned a number, print that number
            }
            else
            {
                // If it returned 0 (i.e. 'uppercaseLetter' wasn't an uppercase letter
                //   then just print the character (which will print out the "1-800-" part)
                System.out.print(c);
            }
        }

        // It's recommended that you close input, although you don't really need to for small programs
        //   like this. Just a good habit to get into.
        input.close();
    }
}
```

**Edit:**
Ben in the comments is correct that this code does not satisfy your given requirements completely.

- Instead of printing each character, you are supposed to append it to a string (i.e. By using the += operator) and then print out the string
- I was checking if the function getNumber failed as a test for uppercase letter, but the requirements suggest that you should only run getNumber if the character is an uppercase letter using the test (c >= 'A' && c <= 'Z') or the equivalent test using numbers.

You should use this as an opportunity to understand the code and update it to match your requirements fully.

Comment: Also, since he was intended to build the string input and then display, consider updating to reflect that

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use a hash? It would be much easier.

Here's a hint to get you going:

```
import java.util.*;

class HelloWorldApp {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    HashMap<Character, Integer> myMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
    myMap.put(new Character('A'), new Integer(2));
    System.out.println(myMap.get('A'));
   }
}
```

Comment: I have not gone over "hash" in my course yet, so to do so would be incorrect for this project.